# How does spring mvc annotation driven link a repository object

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, dao, spring-aop, autowired

I am using Spring MVC annotation driven configuration. I have a repository class named `ProductRepository` annotated with `@Repository`. In my `ProductController` class I have a private field `ProductRepository productRepository` annotated with `@Autowired`.

1. Is the following correct? I want to verify if my precise understanding is correct? Is there any other technical detail that would be a good supplement to this? Now when the web app is initialized a bean is created for each of the annotated classes in  `<context:component-scan>`. During request processing when I access `productRepository` a call to Spring libraries finds a bean of type `ProductRepository` and then returns a reference to it.
2. May be the answer to this question is predicated on the answer to the previous one. What happens when I have a `IProductRepository` interface and I autowire an instance to this interface. If I have two classes implementing this interface, then how will autowiring find the right bean? Does autowiring work with Interfaces?

I am asking the second question because currently I am autowiring instances of Repository bean to my Controller class. As a good design practice I found that I should really use a DAO. My understanding is that the DAO (an interface) will be autowired in this case and there can be multiple implementations for this DAO (Hibernate, JDBC). Now if I have multiple Repository classes implementing this DAo interface and my Controller has an autowired field for the DAO interface how will it inject the appropriate DAO implementation?

Do I have to resort to XML configuration? What are my options for Dependency Injection here?

Update:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at repository.ProductRepository.findProductByCollectionNumber(ProductRepository.java:179)
    at repository.ProductRepository$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ecfba3d5.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at repository.ProductRepository$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b45a8183.findProductByCollectionNumber(<generated>)
    at controller.ProductController.findProductPagination(ProductController.java:198)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Autowiring by type, if more than one bean is found the bean factory rise a `Exception`.
You can solve it using `@Qualifier` annotation, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers

or switching to Autowiring by name with `@Resource` annotation.

Comment: Not at all. Autowiring is done on bean instantiation, by a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, not in each request.

Comment: OK ... my understanding was based on some exception stacktraces (see updated question) which pointed to some lines inside spring code which suggested that autowiring been done at runtime. I removed the Repository annotations and saw the exception being thrown at server startup which confirms what you said. Can you explain why the exception points to code inside spring framework. Is the autowired object decorated by the implementation? What is the reason?

Comment: It's an AOP Transactional Proxy, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained